# Open questions on (finite) tensor categories

Tags: reference-request, qa.quantum-algebra, fusion-categories, open-problems

I would like to know about problems on (finite) tensor categories. I have read Etingof´s notes from his course at MIT. I have a question:

There exists any reference where I can find an open problem about this topic?

Thank you very much for your attention.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We made a [list of open problems](http://aimpl.org/fusioncat/) at an AIM conference a few years ago.